# How to fake own IP in local using GeoIP apache module

Tags: apache, localhost

I need to test GeoIP apache module in local before seding it to production. For that, I need to send a fake IP when visiting an adress and not 127.0.0.1.

**Question** : Is there a way to fake localhost IP ?  By configuring Apache for example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using cURL to do it.
There is an option in GeoIP when a proxy is used that make GeoIP to take in account the `X-Forwarded-For` header element. So by sending `curl --header "X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4" "http://your.site/path` The job is done.

More info on https://serverfault.com/questions/747154/how-to-test-conditions-in-apache-configuration/747405#747405